# Bind IntegerProperty to DoubleProperty

Tags: binding, properties, javafx

I would like to create a bidirectional binding between an IntegerProperty and a DoubleProperty. A converter function would be easy to write to create the mapping between the two values, but I cannot find a way to do it. I am looking for something similar in functionality to StringConverter, but with generic parameters.

Is there a way to do it in JavaFX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they're both implementations of `Property<Number>` it should just work:

```
    DoubleProperty d = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    d.bindBidirectional(i);
```