# Why IntegerProperty implements Property<Number> and not Property<Integer>?

Tags: java, generics, javafx

The `Property` interface added by JavaFX has a type parameter `T`, which is the type of the value wrapped by the property.

Among the implementations of the `Property` interface, there are some for numbers: `IntegerProperty`, `FloatProperty`, etc. All these classes implement `Property<Number>`.

Let's take `IntegerProperty` for example. What is the reason why it implements `Property<Number>` and not `Property<Integer>` as I would have expected?

---

Here is an UML diagram which clarify the hierarchy of `IntegerProperty`:

[image]

Comment: I have the weirdest sense of déjà vu. Have you asked this question before?

Comment: @Kayaman No, never asked before. I've also done my best to check if someone else already did.

Comment: Possibly implemented like that to make it easier to bind number properties. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28179293/1288408

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620552/why-does-longproperty-implement-propertynumber-but-not-propertylong   I find the comments by @James_D in this linked question very informative. He also links this discussion - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8125218

Comment: The generic treatment of numbers using the `Number` base class is always a bit tricky. But note that many casts (and thus, many errors) can easily be avoided: You often do **not** need to cast the value obtained from such a property, as in `Integer i = (Integer)p.getValue()`. Instead, you often can use the appropriate method, as in `Integer i = p.getValue().intValue();`. (This probably does not cover *all* cases, but most of them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section of a Java bug report ([DoubleProperty has unexpected generics type](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8115550)),

> This design is intended. It keeps the number of required methods significantly smaller.

---

In this answer's comments, [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) made me aware of a later bug report adressing that issue, [ChangeListener cannot be added to SimpleIntegerProperty](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8125218)). The comment

> We decided not to change the generics of primitive types properties (from Number to specific type) due to backward-compatibility issues. However, it means this issue cannot be fixed.

suggests that the team considered changing the design, but it was too late.

Comment: I have to agree with the comment there by Randahl Isaksen: "Still, to me this seems to be an improper use of generics. Java developers who are used to generics will expect that a FruitCrate which uses generics is a Crate<Fruit> not a Crate<Object>. The whole purpose of using generics is to ensure compile time type safety and less casting. With this design, you cannot fully guarantee the proper use of types at compile time and you still require casting.

I am aware that this design may simplify your API internally, but externally, this decreases the quality of the JavaFX API."

Comment: In much later comments from the JavaFX developer team (see e.g. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2014-February/012739.html) you start to see references to "we tried to fix this but it was too late", which suggest to me that while it may have been intended, it was a mistake. There are other solutions that don't involve combinatorially exploding the API, e.g. `public abstract class NumberProperty<N extends Number> implements Property<N>` and `public class IntegerProperty extends NumerProperty<Integer>`, as has been suggested by a number of people.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that they use `Number`, so you can use those classes with `AtomicInteger` and `BigInteger` etc. as well.

As far as i can tell, the only "real" difference between `DoubleProperty` and `IntegerProperty` is the Method `setValue(Number v)` - one uses `v.doubleValue()`, the other `v.intValue()`.

I don't have a working javafx environment here, so i can't test, if using  `IntegerProperty` with a `Double` would throw an exception.